# collapsing vertical menu while using css tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a 3 column layout that is made with css tables so each column can fill the browser perfectly. The first column is actually a menu and I need it to hide / move to the left on click and the middle column to fill in that space. It should actually not move completely out of screen but leave a little bit exposed so the user can click that area to have it animate back in.

Heres my fiddle...http://jsfiddle.net/VJmfq/

Right now I noticed the first column wont even move unless you either completely display:none the content inside or animate its content width to 0px(but as I want the column a little exposed I really dont want to be eliminating its content).

I tried animating the inner contents width down but when you animate width it comes in from both sides, so that trick wouldnt work, For example , The inner content should butt up against the right side of the first column but if you use float:right it messes up the content in the middle column, so the content in the first row is up against the side using margin-left...and if I animate the width down it doesnt animate from the left side, the width gets smaller from both sides at the same time.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".two").click( function(event){
event.preventDefault();
if ($(this).hasClass("isDown") ) {
    //Show before animation!
    $(".one").stop().animate({width:"197px"}, 170);
    $(".one div").stop().animate({width:"137px"}, 310, function(){

    });
    $(this).removeClass("isDown");
} else {
    //Hide after animation!
    $(".one").stop().animate({width:"10px"}, 310);
    $(".one div").stop().animate({width:"5px"}, 310, function(){

    });
    $(this).addClass("isDown");
}
return false;
});
});
```

like I said I can get it moving without content inside by just reducing its width but the code I supplied is trying to do it with content inside so it doesnt even really work.

I would love to be able to just say first column marginLeft:-185px and pull the middle section over with it but that doesnt even move the column I think because of the css table layout

Comment: "CSS tables" is a thing?

Comment: lol yea...display:table and display:table-cell for the containers inside main container

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think it is all about the widths.  You need to remove the width from `div.two`, and then in your animate functions, make sure that you always end up with `div.one` being 50px (margin-left) wider than `div.one div`.  At least, it seems to work for me.  http://jsfiddle.net/VJmfq/1/

Comment: ya that actually helped...I got it working using margin-left so I can make the content move out of the way and the container can get as small as it needs to....on my site after it animates the huge image that is in a li in that column pops out of the container.......I think I just need to animate every object inside the container separately to achieve the effect of everything moving to the left... Im gonna wait a bit to choose this as the answer to see if anyone else chimes in with amazing jquery or something..I'll give it a few hours....thanks!

Comment: is there a way to just force the column to move marginLeft:-197px? moving all the elements inside is getting really messy and when I reduce width its not working with the images inside to well

Comment: how's this: http://jsfiddle.net/VJmfq/4/  I set col1 to width:0 (which gives it a shrink-to-fit property like a regular td) and then just animated the width of that inner div.